# Using "fs" to read JSON file throws "invalid json" Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

This makes me crazy. I don't know why but when I use the filesystem `require('fs')` to read valid Json file I get error: Invalid json. Here it is the code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const FILE_NAME = './json.json'

/*
// This way it works!
var jsonData = require('./json.json')
console.log(jsonData);
*/

async function readFile(filePath){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
            if(err){
              console.log("Cant read the file " + err);
              reject(err)
            }
            else{
              resolve(contents)
            }
        })
    })
}

async function getNames(fileName){
  readFile(fileName).then(function(data){
    try {
      console.log(`Type of data: ` + typeof data);
      console.log("File data: " + data);
      return JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error( "Invalid JSON: " + error);
    }
  }).then(function(data){
    console.log(`FILE OBJECT: ` + data);
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
  })
}
getNames(FILE_NAME)
```

This is the file content:

```
{
  "name": "riko"
}
```

This is the console output:

```
Type of data: string
File data: {
  "name": "riko"
}
Error: Invalid JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at C:\Users\rojer\Desktop\Node\test\main.js:31:13
```

I know I could use `var jsonData = require('./json.json')`, but

1. I want to know the reason it doesn't work.
2. What if the JSON data is embedded somewhere in a regular text file.

[image]

There seems to be some garbage.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Have you actually opened the `json.json` file and see what's inside? try reading the exception message, it'll tell you which line it failed to parse.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem, if I copy that code and put valid JSON in `./json.json`, it works. Perhaps you're in a different directory when you run your code? `require('./json.json')` and `readFile('./json.json')` can read **different** files, because the former is relative to the module it appears in, but the latter is relative to the current directory when run.

Comment: @Neverever & Jonas - The OP claims that `require('./json.json')` works. I wondered if Node.js allows JavaScript literals rather than strictly requiring JSON in that situation, but it strictly requires JSON.

Comment: If `require()` works means it has `module.export = ...` at the end of file, which is NOT a valid JSON.

Comment: @Neverever - Node.js's `require` supports loading JSON directly; more: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_require_id

Comment: Edited the post to add more info

Comment: Can someone reproduce the problem?

Comment: *"Can someone reproduce the problem?"* As I [said above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55775900/using-fs-to-read-json-file-throws-invalid-json-node-js/55775991#comment98224178_55775900), I tried and couldn't. I suggest using a hexdump program or binary editor to see **exactly** what the contents of `json.json` are.

Comment: @Hairi - Please don't swear on SO, not even with `*` in or in an initialism. It's not appropriate for this semi-professional environment.

Comment: @Hairi - Turns out my answer yesterday was right, and my test of `require` was broken (I hadn't written out my JSON file correctly). I've undeleted the answer and fixed some of the details. Should work for you now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
Error: Invalid JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at C:\Users\rojer\Desktop\Node\test\main.js:31:13
```

tells us that there's an invisible character at the beginning of the file, probably a [byte order mark (BOM)](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html), that `require` is handling but your code isn't. If the file is really in UTF-8, that BOM will be `\xEF\xBB\xBF`. Once read as UTF-8 into a JavaScript string, that will be the code point `\u{FEFF}` (because JavaScript strings are UTF-16 [but tolerate invalid surrogate pairs]). **Update**: Your binary listing of it confirms that.

I can confirm that if I have a UTF-8 JSON file with a BOM, `require` reads it and handles the BOM, but `readFile` returns the contents of the with the BOM intact, which trips up `JSON.parse`.

You can check for the BOM and strip it off, see `***` lines:

```
const UTF8_BOM = "\u{FEFF}";                      // ***
async function getNames(fileName){
  readFile(fileName).then(function(data){
    try {
      console.log(`Type of data: ` + typeof data);
      if (data.startsWith(UTF8_BOM)) {            // ***
          data = data.substring(UTF8_BOM.length); // ***
      }
      console.log("File data: " + data);
      return JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error( "Invalid JSON: " + error);
    }
  }).then(function(data){
    console.log(`FILE OBJECT: ` + data);
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
  })
}
```

---

Alternately, if you don't want the BOM there, here's a quick and dirty tool to add/remove BOMs on UTF-8 files:

```
const fs = require("fs");

const UTF8_BOM = "\u{FEFF}";

const actions = new Map([
    ["-a", addBOM],
    ["-r", removeBOM],
    ["-t", toggleBOM]
]);

main();

function main() {
    const filename = process.argv[2];
    const option = process.argv[3] || "-t";
    const action = actions.get(option);

    if (!filename) {
        help();
        return;
    }

    if (!action) {
        console.error(`Invalid option ${option}`);
        help();
        return;
    }

    fs.readFile(filename, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(`${filename}: Error reading file: ${err}`);
            return;
        }
        const hasBOM = data.startsWith(UTF8_BOM);
        action(filename, data, hasBOM);
    });
}

function writeResult(filename, data, toggle, successMessage, failMessage) {
    fs.writeFile(filename, data, "utf-8", (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(`${filename}: ${failMessage}: ${err}`);
        } else {
            console.log(`${filename}: ${successMessage}${toggle ? " (toggled)" : ""}`);
        }
    });
}

function addBOM(filename, data, hasBOM, toggle) {
    if (hasBOM) {
        console.log(`${filename}: Already has a BOM`);
    } else {
        writeResult(filename, UTF8_BOM + data, toggle, "Added BOM", "Error adding BOM");
    }
}

function removeBOM(filename, data, hasBOM, toggle) {
    if (!hasBOM) {
        console.log(`${filename}: Already doesn't have a BOM`);
    } else {
        writeResult(filename, data.substring(UTF8_BOM.length), toggle, "Removed BOM", "Error removing BOM");
    }
}

function toggleBOM(filename, data, hasBOM) {
    if (hasBOM) {
        removeBOM(filename, data, hasBOM, true);
    } else {
        addBOM(filename, data, hasBOM, true);
    }
}

function help() {
    console.log("Usage: node utf8bomtoggle [filename] {options}");
    console.log("{options} can be:");
    console.log("  -t   Toggle a BOM [default]");
    console.log("  -a   Add a BOM if not present");
    console.log("  -r   Remove a BOM if present");
}
```